# LINUX + Windows (network incompatibility)

Tags: linux, windows, wireless-networking

I'm having some strange problem in my house. I live with 2 friends, and we have 3 notebooks. Until yesterday, all 3 using Windows. All 3 are connected to the same wi-fi router. Yesterday I installed Elementary OS (Ubuntu-like distro) and now when I connect my notebook to internet, the other 2 notebooks can't use internet regularly. I mean, they are still connected to the network, but they cannot open a web page as always. They have a really slow connection. By the other hand, internet in my notebook works perfect.

I don't know if this is possible, sounds very rare to me.

EDIT: I solved it! It was wireless card driver's fault! I installed other driver and now I'm good..

Thanks for helping!

Comment: does this occur when you are connected via wifi or ethernet? How about your friends? Can you check whether this behavior disappear if, for instance, you are all connected via wifi, or via ethernet?

Comment: Maybe you Ubuntu has an **enabled DHCP-Server**? Check the IPs of your Notebooks...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your new Operating System is requesting a large amount of bandwidth from your router. Most routers have a built-in feature called Quality of Service built in, that you can use to limit your bandwidth allocation.

To access your router, [click here](http://bit.ly/internal-ip). You can find a list of commonly used usernames and passwords [here](http://timtechsoftware.com/?p=895).

Once you're logged into your router, look for a page titled "QoS". It may be under the section "Applications & Gaming" or something similar. If you can't find it, try copy+pasting this link into your browser - `http://192.168.1.1/QoS.asp`.

Once you're on the Quality of Service page, enable it. In the settings, browse to MAC Addresses and find your MAC Address (it will already be filled out if you are accessing it with your notebook). Set the priority to Medium and save your settings.

Your notebook will hopefully not take up too much bandwidth anymore. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sounds like a good explanation. But I can't find any "qos" option in my router. is a Cisco DPC2325.

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga If this is your router - http://reviews.cnet.com/routers/cisco-model-dpc2325-docsis/4507-3319_7-34832238.html - QUality of Service is listed as a feature. What categories are your router's settings split into? Look for a `QoS` subdirectory/page.